# Zendesk form on mobile changes my website html content and css when open/close

Tags: html, css, iframe, mobile, zendesk

I have the Zendesk script put in a common tag for desktop & mobile with specific configs for theme colors and contact form. 
On desktop it works fine but when open on mobile it puts me **position: fixed;** on **body** and after close it all my imgs are bigger(it changes widths) + some white spacesc between content.

I restricted the heights of my images and they look ok but the html content it looks bad till the Zendesk refreshes(between slick carousel). Does anyone know what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It has problems interacting with slick carousel but this css fixed it.

```
div.slick-slider {
  width: 1px;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```